# Regex extract word starting with a set string and ending the line or ending with ;

Tags: regex

I'd like to extract one or more word from a string containing multiple words matching the same pattern (regex python). Here's the line:

> new_appointment_requested; general; SAT-newlead

From that line, I need to extract "SAT-" and whatever comes after it within that word. In this case the output should be "SAT-newlead". It can also be SAT-oldlead or something completely different, and there can be more than one word containing this pattern at a time. To capture all possible scenarios:

1. find the word starting with "SAT-" (\b)
2. if it is the final or only word in the string, extract the rest of the
   word,
3. if there is a ; after the word (it's not the final word in the
   string), grab the word without the ;
4. if more than one word matches this pattern, extract all instances as separate words

For some reason I can't wrap my head around Regex, so any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/smxW4g/1)?

Comment: This is great. I had played with it on regex101, but I couldn't get the output to work. Thanks for the elegant solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Match `SAT` and everything not a space, semicolon or newline:

```
\bSAT[^ ;\n]*
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/8IObGlcG6fB9jB).

Comment: @codefame: Please accept an answer that helped you (green tick on the left).