# SQL: RegEx to grab table names in metadata on Snowflake

Tags: sql, regex, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I've got a table of queries on Snowflake, which I'm trying to parse with RegEx to grab all table names:

| PARENTID | TABLE_NAME |
| --- | --- |
| 01 | Select ... From V820LF.IIM as IIM Join V820LUF.IIME as IIME on IIM.IPROD = IIME.IMPROD Left join (Select CCCODE, CCDESC, CCNOT1 from V820LF.ZCC |
| 02 | Select .. As From V820LF.IIM as IIM Join V820LUF.IIME as IIME on IIM.IPROD = IIME.IMPROD Left join (Select CCCODE, CCDESC From V820LF.ZCC Where CCTABL = 'SIRF1') as C On IIM.IREF01 = C.CCCODE Left outer join (Select CCCODE, CCDESC From V820LF.ZCC Where CCTABL = 'SIRF2') as SC On IIM.IREF02 = SC.CCCODE Left outer join (Select CCCODE, CCDESC From V820LF.ZCC Where CCTABL = 'SIRF3') as ISC On IIM.IREF03 = ISC.CCCODE Left outer join (Select CCCODE, CCDESC From V820LF.ZCC Where CCTABL = 'SIRF4') as PG On IIM.IREF04 = PG.CCCODE Left outer join (Select CCCODE, CCDESC From V820LF.ZCC Where CCTABL = 'USER0107') as PT On IIM.IFCI = PT.CCCODE Left outer join (Select CCCODE, CCDESC from V820LF.ZCC Where CCTABL = 'PRDBRAND') as B On IIME.IMBRND = B.CCCODE Left outer join (Select CCCODE, CCDESC from V820LF.ZCC Where CCTABL = 'PRDBRGRP') as BG On IIME.IMBRGP = BG.CCCODE Left outer join (Select CCCODE, CCDESC, CCSDSC from V820LF.ZCC Where CCTABL = 'ITEMDISC') as DC On IIM.IDISC = DC.CCCODE Left outer join (Select CCCODE, CCDESC, CCNOT1 from V820LF.ZCC Where CCTABL = 'PRDSSTRM') as SS On IIME.IMSSTM = SS.CCCODE |
| 03 | Select ... |

```
with data as 
(select 
parentid,
table_name 
FROM
    prod.log_analytics.metadata),
froms as
(select any_value(data.parentid) parentid, listagg(regexp_substr(value, '\.[^\.]+\.'), '   ') dependencies
from data, table(split_to_table(upper(table_name), 'FROM '))
where index>1
group by seq)
SELECT * FROM froms;
```

But I have the wrong RegEx format, output:

| PARENTID | DEPENDENCIES |
| --- | --- |
| 01 | V820LF. V820LUF. V820LF. |
| 02 | V820LF. V820LUF. V820LF. V820LF. V820LF. V820LF. V820LF. V820LF. V820LF. V820LF. |

How can I adjust the RegEx to grab both before and after the periods?

Planning to tweak this to capture more complicated conditions like implicit joins, sub queried joins etc, but I wonder if it can all be done with a few RegEx instead of multiple queries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will grab everything before and after the period after `'FROM '`

```
'\.[^\.]+\.[^.][^ ;\n()]*')
```

where `[^ ;\n()]*` is everything not a space, semicolon, parenthesis or newline (Thanks to this post [Regex extract word starting with a set string and ending the line or ending with ;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69428411/regex-extract-word-starting-with-a-set-string-and-ending-the-line-or-ending-with))

| PARENTID | DEPENDENCIES |
| --- | --- |
| 01 | V820LF.IIM V820LF.ZCC V820LF.ZCC V820LF.ZCC V820LF.ZCC V820LF.ZCC V820LF.ZCC V820LF.ZCC V820LF.ZCC V820LF.ZCC |
| 02 | V820LF.IIM V820LF.ZCC V820LF.ZCC V820LF.ZCC V820LF.ZCC V820LF.ZCC V820LF.ZCC V820LF.ZCC V820LF.ZCC V820LF.ZCC |
| 03 | V820LF.RCM V820LF.ZCC V820LF.ZCC V820LF.ZCC V820LF.ZCC V820LF.ZCC V820LF.ZCC V820LF.ZCC V820LF.ZCC V820LF.ZCC V820LF.ZCC V820LF.ZCC V820LF.ZCC |
| 04 | V820LF.RCM V820LF.ZCC V820LF.ZCC V820LF.ZCC V820LF.ZCC V820LF.ZCC V820LF.ZCC V820LF.ZCC V820LF.ZCC V820LF.ZCC V820LF.ZCC V820LF.ZCC |

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be better to use the access_history view to find out the dependencies:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/access-history.html

PS: It requires enterprise edition

Comment: Hmm this is interesting but will it work on ETL framework ? Ie, the initial raw snowflake table doesn't have any of the underlying dependent tables, transform happens in Azure data factory.This snowflake metadata table is infact just pullng the metadata logs stored on our azure SQL instance.